# Splitting a table to optimize delete duration

Tags: sql

Consider a table `invoice_data` containing data about invoices over 12 years. This data will be loaded into a cube every day. With every load, the newest 2 years get deleted from `invoice_data` and the data of the last 2 years gets imported by the live system again. (We do that, because values may change in older data sets, too)

This `delete` statement takes about 15 minutes, but we can't use a `truncate`, because we would have to load the whole 12 years which will take much longer.

**Question:**

Is it a good design to split a large table `invoice_dat` like this

- `invoice_data_old`, which contains `years < actual year - 2`
- `invoice_data_new`, which contains  `years >= actual year -2`

This way, we could use a `truncate` on `invoice_data_new` and there is no need to use a `delete` statement?

Are there any better approaches?

**I am using SQL SERVER 2008, but i think this is a general question.**

Comment: What edition of SQL Server 2008?

Comment: We are using SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best approach to this problem is 'horizontal partioning'. Basically, you create a sliding window of data - as a new period of data is added at the end, the old data is removed at the beginning.

Over the course of 4 years, you might have 48 partitions (one per month).

The big advantage with this approach is that SQL server is aware that the data is partioned in this way, and can automatically optimise queries to only use partitions that have relevant data - i.e. when you `select` data from the last month, SQL Server will know to only search one partition, or 1/48th of the data.

Another important aspect is that removing the oldest partition becomes a metadata operation, so does not lock anything.

The downside of this approach is that it does take more effort in terms of setting up and maintaining (unless you write some automated month-end scripts, which may be a non-trivial exercise)

Comment: Did you mean to say 'horizontal partitioning'? Vertical partitioning is to break the table into multiple tables such that the union of columns of all the resultant tables is the complete set of columns in the initial table.

Comment: So to be clear, with this approach i would delete the values of the latest partition and *indirectly* the table data?

Comment: you don't actually delete them as such, you just indicate to SQL Server that the oldest partition is no longer relevant - this is why the 'delete' operation is so quick.

Comment: similarly, you can add a new partition 'offline' (at your leisure) and once the load is complete, just let SQL server know that it's there and it can add it virtually seamlessly.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle, you would use a partitioned table (partitioned by the year). You could then

- load the data into two new tables
- use partition exchange to swap the existing partitions with the new data
- drop the old data

The swapping of the partitions is very fast.
Apparently SQL Server has something very similar - see [SO question on Partition Exchange in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011468/partition-exchange-as-publishing-technique-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

- Partition your table by day
- drop partitions from last two years
- import new data